# Extract multiple values from factor variable based on other factors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically I would like to have new dataframe, coming from Extract multiple values from factor variable based on other factors in R, to be used later as ggplot's geom_text in facet_wrap labels.

I tried and search and search, could not find what I need. I am sorry if turn out there is already this kind of question, and please show me the way to the link

```
year <- c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,2004,2004,2004,2005,2005)
skor <- c("A","B","C","A","C","E","F","A","D","D","E","H","J","K")
year <- as.factor(year)
data <- data.frame(year,skor)

> data
   year skor
1  2000    A
2  2000    B
3  2000    C
4  2001    A
5  2001    C
6  2002    E
7  2002    F
8  2002    A
9  2003    D
10 2004    D
11 2004    E
12 2004    H
13 2005    J
14 2005    K
```

I would like to have new dataframe like this (or something similar), to be used later as ggplot's geom_text (**skor**) in facet_wrap (**year**)

```
year    skor
2000    A,B,C
2001    A,C
2002    E,F,A
2003    D
2004    D,E,H
2005    J,K
```

I tried and search and search, could not find what I need. I am sorry if turn out there is already this kind of question, and please show me the way to the link

Thanks

**EDIT:** I've changed variable skor2 to skor, in the question, for other to be able to follow/reproduce. I used other name skor2 for ggplot later

Comment: `aggregate(skor2 ~ year, data=data,paste0,collapse=",")`